# Generic attribute sets for angular elements

Tags: angular

Across our project we have bunch of controls with similar properties. Is there way to have generic extension which add such shared attributes so it can be changed across whole project in single place?

For instance, typeahead declaration looks like:

```
 <input type="text" name="certificate.title" class="form-control" [class.is-invalid]="invalid('certificate.title')" autocomplete="off" required
                   [(ngModel)]="editModel.certificate.title"
                   [typeahead]="getTypeahead(dt.Certification, editModel.certificate.title, true)"
                   (typeaheadOnSelect)="select($event, editModel.certificate)"
                   [typeaheadOptionsLimit]="10"
                   [typeaheadMinLength]="2"
                   typeaheadWaitMs="400"
                   typeaheadOptionField="title" 
                   typeaheadPhraseDelimiters=" "/>
```

and class, autocomplete, typeaheadOptionsLimit, typeaheadMinLength, typeaheadWaitMs and typeaheadPhraseDelimiters attributes are common.

It would be great to have some generic declarative way to add all common properties to every control, e.g.

```
 <input type="text" name="certificate.title" [class.is-invalid]="invalid('certificate.title')" required
                   [(ngModel)]="editModel.certificate.title"
                   [typeahead]="getTypeahead(dt.Certification, editModel.certificate.title, true)"
                   (typeaheadOnSelect)="select($event, editModel.certificate)"
                   typeaheadOptionField="title" 
                   **attributeSet="GenericTypeahead"** />
```

As a bonus, it would be great to have ability to override attributes.

Comment: You could wrap the input element in a custom component, as shown in [this article](http://blog.rangle.io/angular-2-ngmodel-and-custom-form-components/). Default attributes, directives and event handlers could be applied to the input element, with the possibility to override them through `@Input` and `@Output` properties of the component.

Answer (score 0):

You have a few choices:

You can either put global options in the environment-files (dev and prod and any other environment you define). When compiled, they change to regular js-functions/objects, so you can change their values at run-time as well.

Or you can define a global service (used in the app.module's providers) saving those variables and getting injected in your app for accessing its getters.

Or you can use Redux (for example with the NGRX framework) and have a core/app-redux store for variables shared across the app.

For properties changing at runtime, I recommend 3), for properties set at compilation-time, I recommend 1). Note that for bigger apps a redux store is considered a good practice anyway and from the sounds of it your app is big.